# Error thrown when running WCF project with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, connection-string

I get the following Error but my App.Config file has my connection string within it. as Follows

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="InventoryManagerEntities"
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=InventoryManager;Integrated Security=True;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

> The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was
>   generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First
>   development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not
>   remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use
>   Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity
>   Framework connection string is included in the app.config or
>   web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own
>   DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not
>   some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the
>   base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more
>   about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity
>   Framework documentation here:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

Comment: Did you read the exception message?  Are you doing Code First, or Database First/Model First?   Are you creating your own DbConnection?  Etc.....The connection string does not look like an EF connection string, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Can you also post your Context class and your <entityFramework> in the web.config?

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=. this does not look correct.